# Is it possible to sort by 'recently marked as answered'?

Tags: support, feature-request

I often browse specific tags trying to learn from other people's questions - but this only works if there are answers to the question which solve the problem for the question poster.

[image]

The problem for me is that none of these sorting types really provide a good way to find new questions which have accepted/upvoted answers.

Is there a way to do it?
If not, would other people like this?

Comment: I suppose you could search for accepted answers instead of questions and then sort by newest, something like [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=isaccepted%3ayes)?

Answer (score 6):

Just use `isaccepted:yes` after the tags you want in search bar. For example, If you want sort answers by the `python` tag then use `[python] isaccepted:yes` and then click on Newest tab to get the newly accepted answers.